# What will happen if we change "limit as $x$ to constant" with "limit as $f(x)$ to constant" or "limit as $f(x)$ to variable"

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions

What will happen if we change "limit as $x$ to constant" with "limit as $f(x)$ to constant" or "limit as $f(x)$ to variable" ? example ($f(x)=2x$) $$\lim_{f(x)\to3}x^2$$ or $$\lim_{f(x)\to x}8x$$

and what is its geometrical interpretation? thnxx a ton

Comment: What is the meaning of $\lim_{f(x)\to 3}$?

Comment: @John that was my question = )

Comment: If, for example, $f(x)\equiv 3$ ask what $\lim_{f(x)\to 3} x^2$ is makes no sense.

Comment: Well, if you think again the definition of $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$, it is the limit behavior of $f(x)$ when $x$ is closed to $3$. Now $f(x)$ might not be close to $3$ for all $x$, or $f(x) = 3$ for all $x$. In any cases, $\lim_{f(x) \to 3}$ cannot make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a standard definition, since the variable in a limit is "bound" - meaning that in
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow c}g(x)$$
we are really thinking of a point $c$ and a function $g$, and we're just using $x$ to clarify the argument to the function. I would be confused if the $x$ in the limit were changed to $f(x)$ unless the author had explicitly defined it.

We certainly could define
$$\lim_{f(x)\rightarrow c}g(x)=L$$
to mean that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta$ such that
$$|f(x)-c|<\delta \Longrightarrow |g(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$
which would be in line with our standard definition - it's just saying, "by constraining $f(x)$ to be near $c$, we can constrain $g(x)$ to be near $L$." for a continuous, injective $f$, where there is a solution to $f(x)=c$, this is equivalent to
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow f^{-1}(c)}g(x)$$
however, we could imagine trying to saying something like:
$$\lim_{x^2\rightarrow 1}x^4=1$$
but
$$\lim_{x^2\rightarrow 1}x^3$$ would not exist. This sort of expresses a dependence of $g(x)$ upon $f(x)$ - where if $f(x)$ somehow destroys or alters data about the topology (i.e. by not being injective or being discontinuous), one can talk about how other functions relate to it. (e.g. if $g=h\circ f$ for some $h$, we are basically talking about the function $h$ which directly relates one to the other)

In a more general and abstract sense, if you're familiar with topology, we let $A$ be a *set* and $B$ and $C$ be topological spaces with $c\in C$ and $f:A\rightarrow C$ and $g:A\rightarrow B$, then the limit
$$\lim_{f(x)\rightarrow c}g(x)$$
could be taken as the limit
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow c'}g(x)$$
in the space $A\cup \{c'\}$ endowed with the topology where a set $O$ is open if and only if it is the preimage under $f^*$ of an open set in $B$ where we define $f^*$ as
$$f^*(x)=\begin{cases}f(x) &&\text{if }x\in A\\ c &&\text{if }x=c'\end{cases}$$
but this definition is starting to get a bit hairy - since it essentially means we're using $f$ to "lift" a topology from $B$ onto the set $A$ - and it would likely be more convenient to have started with $A$ as a topological space than to have made it one implicitly.

Comment: i prefer your answer over others, but i don't know topology yet

Answer (score 1):

Those expressions aren't normally used. But if there is some interpretation that makes sense and doesn't lead to contradictions, they might be useful in some contexts, as long as the reader knows what's going on.

Let's consider:

$$\lim_{2x \to 3} x^2 \quad (a)$$

If we agree (and I mean **if!**) that $x \to 2/3 \ \text{ as } \ 2x \to 3$ then:

$$\lim_{2x \to 3} x^2 = \lim_{x \to 3/2} x^2 \quad (b)$$

Thus you can say, if you were writing a paper, "whenever I use expressions like $(a)$ in this paper, I mean $(b)$.

However I cannot think of any way to interpret:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{2x \to x} 8x$$

...but if you think of an interpretation that makes sense, ask some mathematicians for feedback, and perhaps you might use it someday when writing a paper, and maybe it will even catch on?

Bottom line: The important part of introducing new, non-standard notation is making sure the reader knows what it means. But this assumes the notation has a meaning, and that the meaning doesn't lead to contradictions.

Comment: $2x\to x$ is equivalent to $2x-x\to x-x$ that is $x\to0$ so that limit is equal to $0$

Answer (score 1):

The classical $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=b$$ translates in the rigorous language of mathematics the intuitive concept:

> the value of the function $f(x)$ is nearest to $b$ as we want if $x$
>   is sufficiently nearest  to $a$.

So,if, for the same $f(x)$ we write:

$$\lim_{f(x) \rightarrow a}f(x)=?$$ this has no intuitive meaning.

We can have some meaning if we write $$\lim_{f(x) \rightarrow a}f^{-1}(x)=?$$ but, in this case, we are searching the limit of the inverse function, and we can pose some intersting problem as to prove if $$\lim_{f(x) \rightarrow b}f^{-1}(x)=a$$.

We can also give some sense to :

$$\lim_{f(x) \rightarrow a}g(x)=?$$

if from $f(x) \rightarrow a$ we can find that $x\rightarrow c$.

And, if $$\lim_{f(x) \rightarrow a}f^{-1}(x)=c$$ than we can search if $$\lim_{f(x) \rightarrow a}g(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow c}g(x)=b$$